# Error "Parameter is required", that doesn't appear in a local code

Tags: javascript, html

Please help me to understand how this thml-code:

```
 <input type="button" value="xxx" border="0" name="checkMeBtn"
 id="checkMe{$AnswersList.puzzleId}" 
 onclick="javascript: var amount=prompt('blabla.','{if $AnswersList.whoTalk}0.5{else}0.1{/if}'); 
 if(amount != null && amount != '')
 {ldelim}checkMePlease({$AnswersList.puzzleId},amount);{rdelim}">
```

using this js-function:

```
function checkMePlease(puzzleId,amount)
```

can generate error: `Parameter "amount" is required`. I checked that {$Id} is not void (=15).

Even more - the code works for my local site version, but once I put it on the server it doesn't work (but it is not like the code doesn't reach the server, the server reacts to other code changes, but whether I write `checkMePlease({$Id},amount)` or `checkMePlease({$Id})` - the result is the same).

P.S. the code after smarty-engine in my local version:

```
    <input type="button" value="xxx" border="0" name="checkMeBtn" id="checkMe<?php echo $this->_tpl_vars['AnswersList']['puzzleId']; ?>
" onclick="javascript: var amount=prompt('blabla.','<?php if ($this->_tpl_vars['AnswersList']['whoTalk']): ?>0.5<?php else: ?>0.1<?php endif; ?>'); if(amount != null && amount != ''){checkMePlease(<?php echo $this->_tpl_vars['AnswersList']['puzzleId']; ?>
,amount);}">
```

Comment: Are you really using jscript? Or did you just mis-tag your question? And what's "thml" code?

Comment: That JavaScript has some pretty obvious syntax errors of a form that suggests you will be running your entire first code block through some sort of template engine. We'd need to see the code after the template has had its way with it.